# PID controllers not controlling drone in simscape

Tags: matlab, simscape

I have made a drone model in simscape by importing CAD design and made control design using four PID controllers for Altituted , Roll , Pitch and Yaw .
[image]
[image]
But when running simulation , drone is quickly jumping off to a much larger height than in the reference height and is not stable . It doesnt look like it is not following the commands of PID .
[image]

In altitde scope it is overshooting a lot against the reference value of 5m .
Is there any problem in simulation or there is something wrong in external forces.

I added torques that came from PID reading on all four revolute joints of motor .
I modelled thrust forces using external force blocks using equation of thrust ($ \k .omega^2 $)  . I expected it to get stable at refernce height and hover around but it just jumps off rapidly and keeps rising with unstable motion .

Comment: There's no way we can replicate your issue from screenshots of a complicated model including subsystems we can't see. Proof read your question imagining you, like us, are coming to this completely cold and without access to your source code and imagine how we might try to answer you. The proofing should include spotting that [TeX is not supported here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/60020/358485). I advise simplifying your problem, make it work with a single PID which only controls one of your 4 degrees of freedom, add scopes to monitor the feedback terms